# Any pointers on using Ropevim? Is it a usable library?

Tags: python, vim, refactoring, rope

Rope is a refactoring library for Python and RopeVim is a Vim plugin which calls into Rope.

The idea of using RopeVim seems great to me, ***is there any documentation on "getting started" with RopeVim?***

I've followed what documentation there is: https://bitbucket.org/agr/ropevim/src/tip/README.txt

I suppose I'm looking for:

- look at this blog post / article
  / link it makes it all make sense.
- alternate recommendations like
  "forget about RopeVim", it doesn't
  work very well or say "use this
  instead of ropevim".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you found only shows the Vim particulars. If you want to see what those rope functions can do, see the [rope documentation](https://github.com/python-rope/rope). Note, it's incomplete and points to the unittests for a full overview of what it can do.

Answer (score 13):

For basic renaming, hover your vim cursor over the variable/method/etc that you wish to rename and then type:

```
:RopeRename <enter>
```

From there it should be self-explanatory. It asks for the root path to the project you wish to do the renaming in. Then it asks you for the new name. Then you can preview/confirm changes.

If you have tab-complete setup in your vim command-area you can look through the other rope features by typing:

```
:Rope<Tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this script and is the best to automate all the process

https://gist.github.com/15067

```
#!/bin/bash

# Plant rope vim's plugin
# This is a script to install or update 'ropevim'
# Copyright Alexander Artemenko, 2008
# Contact me at svetlyak.40wt at gmail com

function create_dirs
{
    mkdir -p src
    mkdir -p pylibs
}

function check_vim
{
    if vim --version | grep '\-python' > /dev/null
    then
echo You vim does not support python plugins.
        echo Please, install vim with python support.
        echo On debian or ubuntu you can do this:
        echo " sudo apt-get install vim-python"
        exit 1
    fi
}

function get_or_update
{
    if [ -e $1 ]
    then
cd $1
        echo Pulling updates from $2
        hg pull > /dev/null
        cd ..
    else
echo Cloning $2
        hg clone $2 $1 > /dev/null
    fi
}

function pull_sources
{
    cd src
    get_or_update rope http://bitbucket.org/agr/rope
    get_or_update ropevim http://bitbucket.org/agr/ropevim
    get_or_update ropemode http://bitbucket.org/agr/ropemode

    cd ../pylibs
    ln -f -s ../src/rope/rope
    ln -f -s ../src/ropemode/ropemode
    ln -f -s ../src/ropevim/ropevim.py
    cd ..
}

function gen_vim_config
{
    echo "let \$PYTHONPATH .= \":`pwd`/pylibs\"" > rope.vim
    echo "source `pwd`/src/ropevim/ropevim.vim" >> rope.vim
    echo "Now, just add \"source `pwd`/rope.vim\" to your .vimrc"
}

check_vim
create_dirs
pull_sources
gen_vim_config
```

Comment: Although your script is useful, this does not answer the questions asked above. This should have been a comment.

Comment: I call bullshit.  This is a great example of 'documentation on "getting started" with RopeVim'

Answer (score -4):

If you can live without vim, use [Eric](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/), which has rope support.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @ryanjdillon yes it does. "Use this instead of RopeVim"

Comment: For as much as it sounds fun to enter a decades long debate :P I think the rating here speaks to how helpful this type of answer is.